# Proper use of Figaro with Heroku (keys upcase/downcase appear twice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables, figaro-ruby

I'm using Heroku, and when I display the config vars:

```
=== someapp-staging Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                           xxx
LANG:                                   en_US.UTF-8
NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY:                  xxx
NEW_RELIC_LOG:                          stdout
RACK_ENV:                               staging
RAILS_ENV:                              staging
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:                      123456
SENDGRID_USERNAME:                      app123456@heroku.com
WEBSOLR_URL:                            https://index.websolr.com/solr/0e1122334455
sendgrid_password:                      654321
sendgrid_username:                      app654321@heroku.com
websolr_url:                            https://index.websolr.com/solr/0e1122334455
```

... some are defined more than once.

Heroku' advice is to set all vars with uppercased keys.
From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-ons:

> Alias names must always conform to the same naming conventions as config vars.They must begin with a letter and can only contain uppercase alphanumeric characters or underscores.

## 1

So... when we execute `figaro heroku:set --remote staging -e staging` for example, why Figaro doesn't automatically set the keys to uppercase?

## 2

What to do next?
Must I set the vars in `application.yml` with mixed keys like:

```
staging:
  <<: *default
  app_name: 'someapp (staging)'
  SENDGRID_USERNAME: app123456@heroku.com
  SENDGRID_PASSWORD: 123456
  WEBSOLR_URL: 'https://index.websolr.com/solr/0e1122334455'
  geocoder_api_key: 'azertyuiop123456789'
  airbrake_project_id: "987654"
  airbrake_project_key: 'a123456z789456123'
```

Thank you

---

*ps: those are not my real credentials.*

---

## update (from laserlemon answer)

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/238

> You should write your application.yml to the exact case your
>   application will use. While Heroku suggests a certain convention,
>   there's no guarantee that everybody will (or can) use that convention
>   consistently across the board. For that reason, Figaro won't
>   automatically upcase, downcase, or otherwise. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: i'm assuming those are not your real keys and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer from Heroku:

> The behaviour of config vars in this case is due to the underlying
>   Linux operating system being case sensitive. "Behind the scenes"
>   config vars are just a way of managing Unix environment variables to
>   be set on the dynos and as such, our handling of these is fairly
>   minimal to keep them consistent with any other Linux based hosts - if
>   we started adapting the case automatically you might find situations
>   where it didn't work locally whereas it did on Heroku.